# JDBC hive connection error in beeline through knox

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, beeline, connection-refused, knox-gateway

I'm a newbie to hdp and knox.

My HDP environment description:

HDP version - 2.6

HS2 is enabled

Hive transport mode - HTTP

Knox installed via ambari

SSL is not enabled

non Kerberized instance

Issue:

I'm trying to connect to HIVE via beeline. The connection string is "!connect jdbc:hive2://:8443/;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway//hive". the user name : admin, password: admin-password. Its throws an an error : "18/06/18 08:17:39 [main]: ERROR jdbc.HiveConnection: Error opening session org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: :8443 failed to respond" and "Error: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://:8443/;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway//hive: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: :8443 failed to respond (state=08S01,code=0)".

Things I've tired:

I've tried changing the httpPath with "cliserver", "gateway/default/hive" and they didn't work.

I've tried to changing the connection url with " !connect jdbc:hive2://:10001/default;transportMode=http; httpPath=cliservice;" it worked but as it doesn't server the purpose of knox. as I'm trying to use exposed hive port.

I appreciate if anyone can help me with detailed solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify trust store and trust store password. e.g.
{code}
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://:8443/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/gateway.jks;trustStorePassword=;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/default/hive" -n admin -p admin-password
{code}

Here we are assuming you have demo ldap setup (not recommended for production).
Also, you need

1. Knox host
2. Knox truststore location (for HDP /var/lib/knox/data-x.x.x.x-xxxx/security/keystores/gateway.jks)
3. Truststore password (default knox)
4. The path should be gateway/default/hive

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton! The following were the reasons why it didn't work: I didn't turn on demo LDAP services. It was unable to connect with trueStore password as Know (default). later figured out that one should use Knox secret password instead of truestorePassword. It only recognizies full qualified domain name instead of IP.